# gnuplot 5 multiplot alignment not backward compatible

Tags: gnuplot

I had a multiplot in gnuplot4 that was perfectly well aligned. With the upgrade to gnuplot5, the multiplot is no longer correctly aligned. The left graph is bigger than expected, and the right graph is missing some lines on the edges.

Result with Gnuplot v5.2 patchlevel 2 (2017-11-01):
[image: Result with Gnuplot v5]

Result with Gnuplot v4.6 patchlevel 6 (September 2014):
[image: Result with Gnuplot v5]

Does someone know what changed exactly so that it is not longer backward compatible? And how could I fix this? Below is the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color
#set colorsequence classic #enable this for Gnuplot v5 color backward compatibility
set output '/tmp/output.eps'

# Setting common traits for all graphs inside multiplot
set size ratio -1
set tic scale 0.2
set xlabel 'column'
set ylabel 'row'
set xrange [-0.5:60.5]
set yrange [60.5:-0.5]
set xtics('0' 0,'5' 5,'10' 10,'15' 15,'20' 20,'25' 25,'30' 30,'35' 35,'40' 40,'45' 45,'50' 50,'55' 55,'60' 60) font ',10'
set ytics('0' 0,'5' 5,'10' 10,'15' 15,'20' 20,'25' 25,'30' 30,'35' 35,'40' 40,'45' 45,'50' 50,'55' 55,'60' 60) font ",10"
set view map
set cbrange [0:3660]
unset colorbox

# Size of multiplot
set size 1.55,0.85
set multiplot

# Graph 0
set size 0.45,0.9
set origin 0.11,0.
set lmargin at screen 0.01
set title 'Case 1' font ',12' textcolor rgb'blue'
splot '/tmp/input.res' matrix with image noti

# Graph 1
set size 0.45,0.9
set origin 0.51,0.
set lmargin at screen 0.51
set ytics('' 0,'' 5,'' 10,'' 15,'' 20,'' 25,'' 30,'' 35,'' 40,'' 45,'' 50,'' 55,'' 60)
unset ylabel
set title 'Case 2' font ',12' textcolor rgb'red'
splot '/tmp/input.res' matrix with image noti

# Graph 2
set size 0.45,0.9
set origin 0.96,0.
set lmargin at screen 0.96
set colorbox vertical user origin graph 1.0+0.12,0.0 size graph 0.1,1.
set cblabel 'content' rotate by -90 offset 2.,1.
set cbtics format '%g'
set label 1 'Plane 0' at graph 1.12,-0.15 textcolor rgb 'green' font ',12'
set title 'Case 3' font ',12' textcolor rgb'forest-green'
splot '/tmp/input.res' matrix with image noti

unset multiplot
```

And here the input.res dummy matrix data file:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180
180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240
240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300
300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360
360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420
420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480
480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539 540
540 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600
600 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 624 625 626 627 628 629 630 631 632 633 634 635 636 637 638 639 640 641 642 643 644 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 652 653 654 655 656 657 658 659 660
660 661 662 663 664 665 666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 694 695 696 697 698 699 700 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 711 712 713 714 715 716 717 718 719 720
720 721 722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730 731 732 733 734 735 736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746 747 748 749 750 751 752 753 754 755 756 757 758 759 760 761 762 763 764 765 766 767 768 769 770 771 772 773 774 775 776 777 778 779 780
780 781 782 783 784 785 786 787 788 789 790 791 792 793 794 795 796 797 798 799 800 801 802 803 804 805 806 807 808 809 810 811 812 813 814 815 816 817 818 819 820 821 822 823 824 825 826 827 828 829 830 831 832 833 834 835 836 837 838 839 840
840 841 842 843 844 845 846 847 848 849 850 851 852 853 854 855 856 857 858 859 860 861 862 863 864 865 866 867 868 869 870 871 872 873 874 875 876 877 878 879 880 881 882 883 884 885 886 887 888 889 890 891 892 893 894 895 896 897 898 899 900
900 901 902 903 904 905 906 907 908 909 910 911 912 913 914 915 916 917 918 919 920 921 922 923 924 925 926 927 928 929 930 931 932 933 934 935 936 937 938 939 940 941 942 943 944 945 946 947 948 949 950 951 952 953 954 955 956 957 958 959 960
960 961 962 963 964 965 966 967 968 969 970 971 972 973 974 975 976 977 978 979 980 981 982 983 984 985 986 987 988 989 990 991 992 993 994 995 996 997 998 999 1000    1001    1002    1003    1004    1005    1006    1007    1008    1009    1010    1011    1012    1013    1014    1015    1016    1017    1018    1019    1020
1020    1021    1022    1023    1024    1025    1026    1027    1028    1029    1030    1031    1032    1033    1034    1035    1036    1037    1038    1039    1040    1041    1042    1043    1044    1045    1046    1047    1048    1049    1050    1051    1052    1053    1054    1055    1056    1057    1058    1059    1060    1061    1062    1063    1064    1065    1066    1067    1068    1069    1070    1071    1072    1073    1074    1075    1076    1077    1078    1079    1080
1080    1081    1082    1083    1084    1085    1086    1087    1088    1089    1090    1091    1092    1093    1094    1095    1096    1097    1098    1099    1100    1101    1102    1103    1104    1105    1106    1107    1108    1109    1110    1111    1112    1113    1114    1115    1116    1117    1118    1119    1120    1121    1122    1123    1124    1125    1126    1127    1128    1129    1130    1131    1132    1133    1134    1135    1136    1137    1138    1139    1140
1140    1141    1142    1143    1144    1145    1146    1147    1148    1149    1150    1151    1152    1153    1154    1155    1156    1157    1158    1159    1160    1161    1162    1163    1164    1165    1166    1167    1168    1169    1170    1171    1172    1173    1174    1175    1176    1177    1178    1179    1180    1181    1182    1183    1184    1185    1186    1187    1188    1189    1190    1191    1192    1193    1194    1195    1196    1197    1198    1199    1200
1200    1201    1202    1203    1204    1205    1206    1207    1208    1209    1210    1211    1212    1213    1214    1215    1216    1217    1218    1219    1220    1221    1222    1223    1224    1225    1226    1227    1228    1229    1230    1231    1232    1233    1234    1235    1236    1237    1238    1239    1240    1241    1242    1243    1244    1245    1246    1247    1248    1249    1250    1251    1252    1253    1254    1255    1256    1257    1258    1259    1260
1260    1261    1262    1263    1264    1265    1266    1267    1268    1269    1270    1271    1272    1273    1274    1275    1276    1277    1278    1279    1280    1281    1282    1283    1284    1285    1286    1287    1288    1289    1290    1291    1292    1293    1294    1295    1296    1297    1298    1299    1300    1301    1302    1303    1304    1305    1306    1307    1308    1309    1310    1311    1312    1313    1314    1315    1316    1317    1318    1319    1320
1320    1321    1322    1323    1324    1325    1326    1327    1328    1329    1330    1331    1332    1333    1334    1335    1336    1337    1338    1339    1340    1341    1342    1343    1344    1345    1346    1347    1348    1349    1350    1351    1352    1353    1354    1355    1356    1357    1358    1359    1360    1361    1362    1363    1364    1365    1366    1367    1368    1369    1370    1371    1372    1373    1374    1375    1376    1377    1378    1379    1380
1380    1381    1382    1383    1384    1385    1386    1387    1388    1389    1390    1391    1392    1393    1394    1395    1396    1397    1398    1399    1400    1401    1402    1403    1404    1405    1406    1407    1408    1409    1410    1411    1412    1413    1414    1415    1416    1417    1418    1419    1420    1421    1422    1423    1424    1425    1426    1427    1428    1429    1430    1431    1432    1433    1434    1435    1436    1437    1438    1439    1440
1440    1441    1442    1443    1444    1445    1446    1447    1448    1449    1450    1451    1452    1453    1454    1455    1456    1457    1458    1459    1460    1461    1462    1463    1464    1465    1466    1467    1468    1469    1470    1471    1472    1473    1474    1475    1476    1477    1478    1479    1480    1481    1482    1483    1484    1485    1486    1487    1488    1489    1490    1491    1492    1493    1494    1495    1496    1497    1498    1499    1500
1500    1501    1502    1503    1504    1505    1506    1507    1508    1509    1510    1511    1512    1513    1514    1515    1516    1517    1518    1519    1520    1521    1522    1523    1524    1525    1526    1527    1528    1529    1530    1531    1532    1533    1534    1535    1536    1537    1538    1539    1540    1541    1542    1543    1544    1545    1546    1547    1548    1549    1550    1551    1552    1553    1554    1555    1556    1557    1558    1559    1560
1560    1561    1562    1563    1564    1565    1566    1567    1568    1569    1570    1571    1572    1573    1574    1575    1576    1577    1578    1579    1580    1581    1582    1583    1584    1585    1586    1587    1588    1589    1590    1591    1592    1593    1594    1595    1596    1597    1598    1599    1600    1601    1602    1603    1604    1605    1606    1607    1608    1609    1610    1611    1612    1613    1614    1615    1616    1617    1618    1619    1620
1620    1621    1622    1623    1624    1625    1626    1627    1628    1629    1630    1631    1632    1633    1634    1635    1636    1637    1638    1639    1640    1641    1642    1643    1644    1645    1646    1647    1648    1649    1650    1651    1652    1653    1654    1655    1656    1657    1658    1659    1660    1661    1662    1663    1664    1665    1666    1667    1668    1669    1670    1671    1672    1673    1674    1675    1676    1677    1678    1679    1680
1680    1681    1682    1683    1684    1685    1686    1687    1688    1689    1690    1691    1692    1693    1694    1695    1696    1697    1698    1699    1700    1701    1702    1703    1704    1705    1706    1707    1708    1709    1710    1711    1712    1713    1714    1715    1716    1717    1718    1719    1720    1721    1722    1723    1724    1725    1726    1727    1728    1729    1730    1731    1732    1733    1734    1735    1736    1737    1738    1739    1740
1740    1741    1742    1743    1744    1745    1746    1747    1748    1749    1750    1751    1752    1753    1754    1755    1756    1757    1758    1759    1760    1761    1762    1763    1764    1765    1766    1767    1768    1769    1770    1771    1772    1773    1774    1775    1776    1777    1778    1779    1780    1781    1782    1783    1784    1785    1786    1787    1788    1789    1790    1791    1792    1793    1794    1795    1796    1797    1798    1799    1800
1800    1801    1802    1803    1804    1805    1806    1807    1808    1809    1810    1811    1812    1813    1814    1815    1816    1817    1818    1819    1820    1821    1822    1823    1824    1825    1826    1827    1828    1829    1830    1831    1832    1833    1834    1835    1836    1837    1838    1839    1840    1841    1842    1843    1844    1845    1846    1847    1848    1849    1850    1851    1852    1853    1854    1855    1856    1857    1858    1859    1860
1860    1861    1862    1863    1864    1865    1866    1867    1868    1869    1870    1871    1872    1873    1874    1875    1876    1877    1878    1879    1880    1881    1882    1883    1884    1885    1886    1887    1888    1889    1890    1891    1892    1893    1894    1895    1896    1897    1898    1899    1900    1901    1902    1903    1904    1905    1906    1907    1908    1909    1910    1911    1912    1913    1914    1915    1916    1917    1918    1919    1920
1920    1921    1922    1923    1924    1925    1926    1927    1928    1929    1930    1931    1932    1933    1934    1935    1936    1937    1938    1939    1940    1941    1942    1943    1944    1945    1946    1947    1948    1949    1950    1951    1952    1953    1954    1955    1956    1957    1958    1959    1960    1961    1962    1963    1964    1965    1966    1967    1968    1969    1970    1971    1972    1973    1974    1975    1976    1977    1978    1979    1980
1980    1981    1982    1983    1984    1985    1986    1987    1988    1989    1990    1991    1992    1993    1994    1995    1996    1997    1998    1999    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2017    2018    2019    2020    2021    2022    2023    2024    2025    2026    2027    2028    2029    2030    2031    2032    2033    2034    2035    2036    2037    2038    2039    2040
2040    2041    2042    2043    2044    2045    2046    2047    2048    2049    2050    2051    2052    2053    2054    2055    2056    2057    2058    2059    2060    2061    2062    2063    2064    2065    2066    2067    2068    2069    2070    2071    2072    2073    2074    2075    2076    2077    2078    2079    2080    2081    2082    2083    2084    2085    2086    2087    2088    2089    2090    2091    2092    2093    2094    2095    2096    2097    2098    2099    2100
2100    2101    2102    2103    2104    2105    2106    2107    2108    2109    2110    2111    2112    2113    2114    2115    2116    2117    2118    2119    2120    2121    2122    2123    2124    2125    2126    2127    2128    2129    2130    2131    2132    2133    2134    2135    2136    2137    2138    2139    2140    2141    2142    2143    2144    2145    2146    2147    2148    2149    2150    2151    2152    2153    2154    2155    2156    2157    2158    2159    2160
2160    2161    2162    2163    2164    2165    2166    2167    2168    2169    2170    2171    2172    2173    2174    2175    2176    2177    2178    2179    2180    2181    2182    2183    2184    2185    2186    2187    2188    2189    2190    2191    2192    2193    2194    2195    2196    2197    2198    2199    2200    2201    2202    2203    2204    2205    2206    2207    2208    2209    2210    2211    2212    2213    2214    2215    2216    2217    2218    2219    2220
2220    2221    2222    2223    2224    2225    2226    2227    2228    2229    2230    2231    2232    2233    2234    2235    2236    2237    2238    2239    2240    2241    2242    2243    2244    2245    2246    2247    2248    2249    2250    2251    2252    2253    2254    2255    2256    2257    2258    2259    2260    2261    2262    2263    2264    2265    2266    2267    2268    2269    2270    2271    2272    2273    2274    2275    2276    2277    2278    2279    2280
2280    2281    2282    2283    2284    2285    2286    2287    2288    2289    2290    2291    2292    2293    2294    2295    2296    2297    2298    2299    2300    2301    2302    2303    2304    2305    2306    2307    2308    2309    2310    2311    2312    2313    2314    2315    2316    2317    2318    2319    2320    2321    2322    2323    2324    2325    2326    2327    2328    2329    2330    2331    2332    2333    2334    2335    2336    2337    2338    2339    2340
2340    2341    2342    2343    2344    2345    2346    2347    2348    2349    2350    2351    2352    2353    2354    2355    2356    2357    2358    2359    2360    2361    2362    2363    2364    2365    2366    2367    2368    2369    2370    2371    2372    2373    2374    2375    2376    2377    2378    2379    2380    2381    2382    2383    2384    2385    2386    2387    2388    2389    2390    2391    2392    2393    2394    2395    2396    2397    2398    2399    2400
2400    2401    2402    2403    2404    2405    2406    2407    2408    2409    2410    2411    2412    2413    2414    2415    2416    2417    2418    2419    2420    2421    2422    2423    2424    2425    2426    2427    2428    2429    2430    2431    2432    2433    2434    2435    2436    2437    2438    2439    2440    2441    2442    2443    2444    2445    2446    2447    2448    2449    2450    2451    2452    2453    2454    2455    2456    2457    2458    2459    2460
2460    2461    2462    2463    2464    2465    2466    2467    2468    2469    2470    2471    2472    2473    2474    2475    2476    2477    2478    2479    2480    2481    2482    2483    2484    2485    2486    2487    2488    2489    2490    2491    2492    2493    2494    2495    2496    2497    2498    2499    2500    2501    2502    2503    2504    2505    2506    2507    2508    2509    2510    2511    2512    2513    2514    2515    2516    2517    2518    2519    2520
2520    2521    2522    2523    2524    2525    2526    2527    2528    2529    2530    2531    2532    2533    2534    2535    2536    2537    2538    2539    2540    2541    2542    2543    2544    2545    2546    2547    2548    2549    2550    2551    2552    2553    2554    2555    2556    2557    2558    2559    2560    2561    2562    2563    2564    2565    2566    2567    2568    2569    2570    2571    2572    2573    2574    2575    2576    2577    2578    2579    2580
2580    2581    2582    2583    2584    2585    2586    2587    2588    2589    2590    2591    2592    2593    2594    2595    2596    2597    2598    2599    2600    2601    2602    2603    2604    2605    2606    2607    2608    2609    2610    2611    2612    2613    2614    2615    2616    2617    2618    2619    2620    2621    2622    2623    2624    2625    2626    2627    2628    2629    2630    2631    2632    2633    2634    2635    2636    2637    2638    2639    2640
2640    2641    2642    2643    2644    2645    2646    2647    2648    2649    2650    2651    2652    2653    2654    2655    2656    2657    2658    2659    2660    2661    2662    2663    2664    2665    2666    2667    2668    2669    2670    2671    2672    2673    2674    2675    2676    2677    2678    2679    2680    2681    2682    2683    2684    2685    2686    2687    2688    2689    2690    2691    2692    2693    2694    2695    2696    2697    2698    2699    2700
2700    2701    2702    2703    2704    2705    2706    2707    2708    2709    2710    2711    2712    2713    2714    2715    2716    2717    2718    2719    2720    2721    2722    2723    2724    2725    2726    2727    2728    2729    2730    2731    2732    2733    2734    2735    2736    2737    2738    2739    2740    2741    2742    2743    2744    2745    2746    2747    2748    2749    2750    2751    2752    2753    2754    2755    2756    2757    2758    2759    2760
2760    2761    2762    2763    2764    2765    2766    2767    2768    2769    2770    2771    2772    2773    2774    2775    2776    2777    2778    2779    2780    2781    2782    2783    2784    2785    2786    2787    2788    2789    2790    2791    2792    2793    2794    2795    2796    2797    2798    2799    2800    2801    2802    2803    2804    2805    2806    2807    2808    2809    2810    2811    2812    2813    2814    2815    2816    2817    2818    2819    2820
2820    2821    2822    2823    2824    2825    2826    2827    2828    2829    2830    2831    2832    2833    2834    2835    2836    2837    2838    2839    2840    2841    2842    2843    2844    2845    2846    2847    2848    2849    2850    2851    2852    2853    2854    2855    2856    2857    2858    2859    2860    2861    2862    2863    2864    2865    2866    2867    2868    2869    2870    2871    2872    2873    2874    2875    2876    2877    2878    2879    2880
2880    2881    2882    2883    2884    2885    2886    2887    2888    2889    2890    2891    2892    2893    2894    2895    2896    2897    2898    2899    2900    2901    2902    2903    2904    2905    2906    2907    2908    2909    2910    2911    2912    2913    2914    2915    2916    2917    2918    2919    2920    2921    2922    2923    2924    2925    2926    2927    2928    2929    2930    2931    2932    2933    2934    2935    2936    2937    2938    2939    2940
2940    2941    2942    2943    2944    2945    2946    2947    2948    2949    2950    2951    2952    2953    2954    2955    2956    2957    2958    2959    2960    2961    2962    2963    2964    2965    2966    2967    2968    2969    2970    2971    2972    2973    2974    2975    2976    2977    2978    2979    2980    2981    2982    2983    2984    2985    2986    2987    2988    2989    2990    2991    2992    2993    2994    2995    2996    2997    2998    2999    3000
3000    3001    3002    3003    3004    3005    3006    3007    3008    3009    3010    3011    3012    3013    3014    3015    3016    3017    3018    3019    3020    3021    3022    3023    3024    3025    3026    3027    3028    3029    3030    3031    3032    3033    3034    3035    3036    3037    3038    3039    3040    3041    3042    3043    3044    3045    3046    3047    3048    3049    3050    3051    3052    3053    3054    3055    3056    3057    3058    3059    3060
3060    3061    3062    3063    3064    3065    3066    3067    3068    3069    3070    3071    3072    3073    3074    3075    3076    3077    3078    3079    3080    3081    3082    3083    3084    3085    3086    3087    3088    3089    3090    3091    3092    3093    3094    3095    3096    3097    3098    3099    3100    3101    3102    3103    3104    3105    3106    3107    3108    3109    3110    3111    3112    3113    3114    3115    3116    3117    3118    3119    3120
3120    3121    3122    3123    3124    3125    3126    3127    3128    3129    3130    3131    3132    3133    3134    3135    3136    3137    3138    3139    3140    3141    3142    3143    3144    3145    3146    3147    3148    3149    3150    3151    3152    3153    3154    3155    3156    3157    3158    3159    3160    3161    3162    3163    3164    3165    3166    3167    3168    3169    3170    3171    3172    3173    3174    3175    3176    3177    3178    3179    3180
3180    3181    3182    3183    3184    3185    3186    3187    3188    3189    3190    3191    3192    3193    3194    3195    3196    3197    3198    3199    3200    3201    3202    3203    3204    3205    3206    3207    3208    3209    3210    3211    3212    3213    3214    3215    3216    3217    3218    3219    3220    3221    3222    3223    3224    3225    3226    3227    3228    3229    3230    3231    3232    3233    3234    3235    3236    3237    3238    3239    3240
3240    3241    3242    3243    3244    3245    3246    3247    3248    3249    3250    3251    3252    3253    3254    3255    3256    3257    3258    3259    3260    3261    3262    3263    3264    3265    3266    3267    3268    3269    3270    3271    3272    3273    3274    3275    3276    3277    3278    3279    3280    3281    3282    3283    3284    3285    3286    3287    3288    3289    3290    3291    3292    3293    3294    3295    3296    3297    3298    3299    3300
3300    3301    3302    3303    3304    3305    3306    3307    3308    3309    3310    3311    3312    3313    3314    3315    3316    3317    3318    3319    3320    3321    3322    3323    3324    3325    3326    3327    3328    3329    3330    3331    3332    3333    3334    3335    3336    3337    3338    3339    3340    3341    3342    3343    3344    3345    3346    3347    3348    3349    3350    3351    3352    3353    3354    3355    3356    3357    3358    3359    3360
3360    3361    3362    3363    3364    3365    3366    3367    3368    3369    3370    3371    3372    3373    3374    3375    3376    3377    3378    3379    3380    3381    3382    3383    3384    3385    3386    3387    3388    3389    3390    3391    3392    3393    3394    3395    3396    3397    3398    3399    3400    3401    3402    3403    3404    3405    3406    3407    3408    3409    3410    3411    3412    3413    3414    3415    3416    3417    3418    3419    3420
3420    3421    3422    3423    3424    3425    3426    3427    3428    3429    3430    3431    3432    3433    3434    3435    3436    3437    3438    3439    3440    3441    3442    3443    3444    3445    3446    3447    3448    3449    3450    3451    3452    3453    3454    3455    3456    3457    3458    3459    3460    3461    3462    3463    3464    3465    3466    3467    3468    3469    3470    3471    3472    3473    3474    3475    3476    3477    3478    3479    3480
3480    3481    3482    3483    3484    3485    3486    3487    3488    3489    3490    3491    3492    3493    3494    3495    3496    3497    3498    3499    3500    3501    3502    3503    3504    3505    3506    3507    3508    3509    3510    3511    3512    3513    3514    3515    3516    3517    3518    3519    3520    3521    3522    3523    3524    3525    3526    3527    3528    3529    3530    3531    3532    3533    3534    3535    3536    3537    3538    3539    3540
3540    3541    3542    3543    3544    3545    3546    3547    3548    3549    3550    3551    3552    3553    3554    3555    3556    3557    3558    3559    3560    3561    3562    3563    3564    3565    3566    3567    3568    3569    3570    3571    3572    3573    3574    3575    3576    3577    3578    3579    3580    3581    3582    3583    3584    3585    3586    3587    3588    3589    3590    3591    3592    3593    3594    3595    3596    3597    3598    3599    3600
3600    3601    3602    3603    3604    3605    3606    3607    3608    3609    3610    3611    3612    3613    3614    3615    3616    3617    3618    3619    3620    3621    3622    3623    3624    3625    3626    3627    3628    3629    3630    3631    3632    3633    3634    3635    3636    3637    3638    3639    3640    3641    3642    3643    3644    3645    3646    3647    3648    3649    3650    3651    3652    3653    3654    3655    3656    3657    3658    3659    3660
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A major change from version 4 to version 5 was to reconcile the various output modes (terminals) so that they behaved more compatibly with each other.  That is, the goal was that a plot composed in an interactive terminal could then be plotted to PostScript or PDF output without having to change all the size, color, linetype, etc commands in order to keep the visual appearance the same. Since the version 4 terminals were not consistent with each other, necessarily some terminal behavior changed such that old scripts would need revision. That was, in fact, the primary reason for bumping the major version from 4 to 5.

In version 4 the PostScript terminal in particular behaved differently from other output modes in that it allowed you to "draw outside the lines" by setting a drawing size greater than 1, e.g. the command in your example `set size 1.55, 0.9`.  It was recommended to avoid this even in version 4, for which the documentation said:

> "set size" is relative to the default size, which differs from
>   terminal to terminal. Since gnuplot fills as much of the available
>   plotting area as possible by default, it is safer to use "set size" to
>   decrease the size of a plot that to increase it.
>   See "set terminal" for the default sizes

A further self-incompatibility in version 4 was the inconsistent results from issuing a `set size` command after, rather than before, a `set terminal` command.  In general it was more reliable to set the size first and then set the terminal (NB: this is no longer relevant in version 5!).

The revised script below should run using version 5, with the added benefit that it is usable for terminal types other than PostScript.  I have commented the lines that changed. Note that the revised script works fine in version 4.6 also.

```
# default eps output size is 5in x 3.5in
## scale this to get the size used by the original v4 script 
##
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color size 7.75in, 2.975in
set output '2243.eps'

# Setting common traits for all graphs inside multiplot
set size ratio -1
set tic scale 0.2
set xlabel 'column'
set ylabel 'row'
set xrange [-0.5:60.5]
set yrange [60.5:-0.5]
set xtics('0' 0,'5' 5,'10' 10,'15' 15,'20' 20,'25' 25,'30' 30,'35' 35,'40' 40,'45' 45,'50' 50,'55' 55,'60' 60) font ',10'
set ytics('0' 0,'5' 5,'10' 10,'15' 15,'20' 20,'25' 25,'30' 30,'35' 35,'40' 40,'45' 45,'50' 50,'55' 55,'60' 60) font ",10"
set view map
set cbrange [0:3660]
unset colorbox

## CHANGE - do not attempt to change terminal output size with 
##          a "set size" command
# Size of multiplot
#set size 1.55,0.85       <<<<<< Never set size greater than 1.0
set multiplot

# Graph 0
##
## set size and origin relative to size of 1.0
## (I don't know what the original "set lmargin" was trying to do)
##
set size 0.45/1.55, 0.9
set origin 0.11/1.55, 0.
#set lmargin at screen 0.01

set title 'Case 1' font ',12' textcolor rgb'blue'
splot '2243.dat' matrix with image noti

# Graph 1
##
## set size and origin relative to size of 1.0
##
set size 0.45/1.55, 0.9
set origin 0.51/1.55, 0.
#set lmargin at screen 0.51

set ytics('' 0,'' 5,'' 10,'' 15,'' 20,'' 25,'' 30,'' 35,'' 40,'' 45,'' 50,'' 55,'' 60)
unset ylabel
set title 'Case 2' font ',12' textcolor rgb'red'
splot '2243.dat' matrix with image noti

# Graph 2
##
## set size and origin relative to size of 1.0
##
set size 0.45/1.55, 0.9
set origin 0.91/1.55, 0.
#set lmargin at screen 0.96

set colorbox vertical user origin graph 1.0+0.12,0.0 size graph 0.1,1.
set cblabel 'content' rotate by -90 offset 2.,1.
set cbtics format '%g'
set label 1 'Plane 0' at graph 1.12,-0.15 textcolor rgb 'green' font ',12'
set title 'Case 3' font ',12' textcolor rgb'forest-green'
splot '2243.dat' matrix with image noti

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some of your commands actually don't make sense, for example: the third (right) plot is positioned at `screen 0.96,0.0` and has `size 0.45,0.9`, which will be outside of the canvas. As @Ethan already explained, the eps still contains the full graph, but apparently with some missing lines in the right plot.

A possible alternative variation would be the script below.
The main differences to your and Ethan's scripts are:

1. parameter variables for margins and gaps which will facilitate your life such that you don't have to recalculate values for the origin and size of the subplots again and again if you want to fine tune the layout.
2. the use of a simple macro to set origin and size of the sub-plots using the index `i`. (Not available in gnuplot 4.6)
3. `plot` instead of `splot`

In case you need 4.6 compatibility, replace:

- `reset session` by `reset`
- `set margins 0,0,0,0` by  `set bmargin 0; set lmargin 0; set rmargin 0; set tmargin 0`
- all `@setMyPlot` by `set origin i*myGrid+myLeftMargin,0;   set size myWidth,1`

**Code:**

```
### multiplot 
reset session
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color size 7.75in, 2.975in
set output '/tmp/output.eps' 

FILE = '/tmp/input.res'

set size square
# dimensions in screen coordinates
set margins 0,0,0,0   # set all margins to 0
myPlotCount = 3       # number of sub-plots
myLeftMargin = 0.07   # left margin of the whole plot
myGap = 0.03          # gap between sub-plots
myColorBox = 0.15     # space for color box
myWidth = (1.0-myLeftMargin-myColorBox-(myPlotCount-1)*myGap)/myPlotCount    # width of a sub-plot
myGrid = myWidth + myGap    # grid of subplots

set xlabel "column"
set xrange[-0.5:60.5]
set ylabel "row"
set yrange[60.5:-0.5]
unset colorbox
set cbrange [0:3660]

# macro to set the sub-plot, based on variable i
setMyPlot = 'set origin i*myGrid+myLeftMargin,0;   set size myWidth,1'

set multiplot

# Graph 0
i=0
@setMyPlot
set title 'Case 1' font ',12' tc rgb 'blue'
plot FILE matrix using 1:2:3 with image notitle

# for the following plots, hide ylabels and ytic-labels, but still show ytics
unset ylabel
set format y ""

# Graph 1
i=1
@setMyPlot
set title 'Case 2' font ',12' tc rgb 'red'
plot FILE matrix using 1:2:3 with image notitle

# set colorbox only for last plot
set colorbox vertical user origin graph 1.1, graph 0 size screen myColorBox*0.25, graph 1
set cblabel 'content' rotate by -90 offset 2,1
set label 1 'Plane 0' at screen 1-myColorBox/2.,0.10 center tc rgb 'green' font ',12'

# Graph 2
i=2
@setMyPlot
set title 'Case 3' font ',12' tc rgb 'forest-green'
plot FILE matrix using 1:2:3 with image notitle

unset multiplot
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice contribution. Should maybe the size set on line "set terminal postscript eps enhanced color size 7.75in, 2.975in" be also dependent on the number of plots?

Comment: of course, you can do this if you want. For example something like: `# sub-plot dimensions in inches` 
`PlotWidth = 2.5` 
`PlotCount = 3` 
`CanvasWidth = sprintf("%fin",PlotCount*PlotWidth)` 
`set terminal postscript eps enhanced color size CanvasWidth, 2.975in`. You could also start specifying the size of a sub-plot and setting the canvas accordingly with space for the y-label and the colorbox.